# ContactID List as URL Parameter

Tags: contacts, search, urls

I am looking for a way to pass a comma separated list of contact ID's to Civicrm in a URL call and return the list like one can do with the Search Builder "in" clause.

The URL will be formed and called by an external app.

I am certian that this could be accomplished by developing an extension but I have no experience doing that. Hoping maybe someone out there has.

Thank you!

Comment: What cms are you using? If you are on drupal have you tried views feed export?

Comment: Oh like a fully formed page - I was thinking they meant a list of data like the REST api - https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/v3/rest. @KeithG what format are you looking to be returned?

Comment: Perhaps worth checking if SearchKit can accept such a list via URL